# $f (x)=\exp(x/2)−25x^2$. Show that f on $ (4\log(20), \infty)$ has exactly one root.

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

Let 
$$f (x)=\exp(x/2)−25x^2$$ 
Show that $f$ on $ (4\log(20), \infty)$ has exactly one root $x^*$. (Note that log the natural logarithm)

I'm struggling with this question, we were given a hint, which was:

Start by noting that

$$f(x)=\bigg( \exp \bigg( \frac{x}{4} \bigg)−5x \bigg)\bigg(\exp\bigg(\frac{x}{4}\bigg)+5x \bigg)$$

However, I'm not sure what to make of this hint. I started with the fact that $h(x) = g(x)-x$ for a fixed point but not sure where to go from there.

Comment: yes! Sorry! it's suppose to be 4log20

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange. Did you try the fix point theorem from banach ?

Comment: I did think about using it but I wasn't sure as I thought in order to show that it is a contraction with a constant, K greater than or equal to zero less than 1 I would have to take the modulus of the differential of f which I thought would be easier done without factorising it (i.e not using the hint) which made me think my lecturer wanted me to do it another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For positive $x$, the function $exp(\frac{x}{4})+5x$ is obviously positive, so the
 only possibility is that $g(x):=exp(\frac{x}{4})-5x$ has a root.

The derivate of $exp(\frac{x}{4})-5x$ is $\frac{1}{4}exp(\frac{x}{4})-5$, which is
 positive for $x>4log(20)$ because the inequality $\frac{1}{4}exp(\frac{x}{x})-5>0$ 
 can be transformed into the inequality $x>4log(20)$. So, there is at most one root
 for $x>4log(20)$. Because of $g(17)<0\ ,\ g(18)>0$, the only root is between $17$ and
 $18$. $$17.99902115409395014389893303$$ is the numerical value of the root.

Comment: This is probably a stupid question but why is it since exp(x/4) +5x is positive we can say that this implies the only possibility is that g(x) := exp(x/4) -5x has a root? I understand the rest of the answer but just wondered why we can say that?

Comment: The exponential function $exp(\frac{x}{4})$ is always positive, so for $x\ge 0$ the function $exp(\frac{x}{4})+5x$ must be positive as well.

Comment: But one of the parantheses must be $0$ because the product is $0$.

Comment: oh ok, Thankyou!